# For a C# method with custom attributes how do we use a parameter passed to the actual method in the attributes constructor?

Tags: c#, web-services, methods, attributes

I have a web service method that takes a complex object and a string (`ActionID`). For the below example how do I pass the `ActionID` to one of my method attributes constructors?

```
[TraceExtensions.TraceExtension(ActionID), System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute(" ", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("RCreateResponse", Namespace = "test")]
public WSRCResponse create([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "test")] WSRCRequest RCreateRequest, string ActionID)
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("create", new object[] { RCreateRequest });
    return ((WSRCResponse)(results[0]));
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your intent here? Because `ActionID` varies per call, but attribute metadata is constant and never changes... I'm not sure how you intend to pass "something variable set at runtime" into "something constant set at compile-time" (the other way around often works, though)

Comment: Attributes have to be constructable at *compile* time. They're embedded in the assembly and can't be changed by values that are only available at *runtime*

Comment: It seems that you may be trying to create an attribute that performs tracing of calls to a WCF proxy. Look into WCF extensibility.

Comment: Thats what I thought but I was hoping there was some way around it. The problem I need to solve is to somehow capture a soap message when the return value of the above invoke is null. I am currently capturing the soap message to a text file in the TraceExtensions class. But I somehow need to pass an ID to this class so that I can store the soap message in the correct place. The TraceExtensions looks like this:

Comment: <AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)> _
Public Class TraceExtensionAttribute
    Inherits SoapExtensionAttribute

    Private m_filename As String = "C:\trace\log.xml"
    Private m_priority As Integer


End Class